# Taptic Engine smooth feedback

Tags: ios, swift

I noticed that when I receive message in iMessage there’s some smooth haptic feedback going on and I don’t know how to make the same effect using Swift. It doesn’t seem like it is an Impact or notification feedback.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's super easy!

You can reach this with just 2 lines of code:

```
if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
    let generator = UISelectionFeedbackGenerator()
    generator.selectionChanged()
}
```

**PS:** There is `if` statement - just in case. If your app running on iOS 10+ you don't need that, obvious.

**PSS:** I'm not sure if it helps you because this method is for selection changes like scrolling a UIPicker or something.

Comment: It’s not really it, but I found a way to make that vibration. If you import ‘AudioToolbox’ module in project you can use method called `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound` that not only plays sound but also a vibration. If you call this method like this `AudioServicesPlaySystemSound(SystemSoundID(1361))` it creates **smooth vibration** and cool sound that’s supposed to be sound of AirPower